# Optional Parameters in Classes in Python

Tags: python, file, class, operating-system

This is my python code to perform operations such as delete, move and rename multiple files. This code works fine for all types of files. Suppose I want to add an optional parameter like to delete files with a ".pdf" extension, how can I add the option? Like it is not compulsory to add it but if you pass it, all the pdf files will be deleted.

I just want to add an optional parameter which when passed, perform the action on only those files

```
import os


class FileOperation:
    def __init__(self, file_loc):
        self.file_loc = file_loc

    def file_location(self):
        print("Source folder contents: ")
        print()
        for i in os.listdir(self.file_loc):
            print(i)
        print()

    def rename_bulk_files(self):
        c = 0
        path = self.file_loc
        for i in os.listdir(self.file_loc):
            dot_index = i.index('.')
            src = os.path.join(path, i)
            dst = os.path.join(path, i[0:dot_index] + "_" + str(c) + i[dot_index:])
            os.rename(src, dst)
            c += 1
        return "Renaming of files has finished"

    def delete_bulk_files(self):
        path = self.file_loc
        for i in os.listdir(self.file_loc):
            file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
            os.remove(file_path)
        print("All files have been deleted")

    def move_bulk_files(self):
        path = self.file_loc
        destination_folder = input("Enter the destination folder / folders separated by a comma: ")
        for i in os.listdir(self.file_loc):
            src_path = os.path.join(path, i)
            des_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, i)
            os.replace(src_path, des_path)
        print("All files have been moved to the destination folder")


source_folder = input("Enter source folder/ folders locations separated by a comma: ")


my_file_operations = FileOperation(source_folder)
my_file_operations.delete_bulk_files()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
files_extension = input(“Enter files extension (defaults to all files if not provided): “)
```

And then in `delete_bulk_files` :

```py
file_path = os.path.join(path, i)
if not files_extension or file_path.endswith(files_extension):
  os.remove(file_path)
```

Comment: Even though this is working, if I don't type anything in file_extension, by default all files should be deleted

Comment: Correct, if you click enter without providing extension it should delete all files